# can someone explain me this strange behaviour of WPF events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a window that creates a list of controls via reflection that are bound as a datacontext to a `TabControl` and to be represented as `ContentPresenter` controls where the content is binded as the created control, which was done by using reflection.

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding sub}" Loaded="smb_Loaded">
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

After the creation I need some stuff to be done to the created controls (every single one of them) like subcribing to their events or runing some methods or threads, so I wanted to have it being done after the initialisation or creation of the object. I tried to have this stuff done after the "Initialized" or "Loaded" Event, but both of them get triggered only the first time, on only the first control I load. 
If I create 3 controls with reflection, I will have 3 tabs whose content is `ContentPresenters` that contain the control. When I select one tab, the event will be triggered. If I then select another one, it won't be triggered at all until I re-run the application.

Comment: Can you please rephrase this part: *stuff to be done to rhe created controls (everyone of them)*? It's hard to understand.

Comment: The tab control is kinda special items control - it shows a list of items (tab items) but there's only one content presenter to show the content of each item. You might want to listen to `SelectionChanged' on the tab control.

Comment: After I create these controls I set the control as the content in a content presenter, like in the code above. I need, after their creation and insertion into the form, to sobscribe to couple of events of these dynamicly created controls as well as do some initialisation stuff. I need a event to trigger after it is created, but the "Isinitialized" event triggers only on the first of the controls. never on the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to changes in the Items collection:

```
 CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(tab.Items).CollectionChanged += (o, ev) =>
 {
    Console.WriteLine("item added");
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

`Initialization` and `loaded` events are run only once when the control is being loaded you should register to `SelectionChanged`event.

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding sub}" Loaded="smb_Loaded">
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

the code behind

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do all your logic here 
    // subscribe to events
}
```

don't forget to unregister previosly registered event of the unselected item.

If `SelectionChanged` event doesn't satisfy your needs register your events when you dynamically create your control, you will have to post the relevant code...

Comment: Selectionchanged is of absolutly no use to me. to register the events I need it to be done  when triggering the initialized eventhandler, but it triggers only on one tabitem. not on the others. This is the strange behaviour.

The selectionchanged event is relevant in this story only that the loaded or initialized eventhandler is triggered on the first time I select it. According to the code I pasted it should trigger on the loading of every tabitem, but it triggers only on one of them-

Comment: @user853710 there is nothing strange about it the tab control itself is loaded once this is why your contentPresenter is being triggered only once. you'll have to post the relevant registering code since its not clear what you are really trying to do and failing

Comment: Is it possible to have it call a method after the object is being created where I can set the event subscribtions manually?

I need to setup some stuff before the user selects a tab

Comment: @user853710 you said you create them dynamically just subscribe there. again post the creation code and the subscription you want to get even as a psudo code...